# Yurt flooring with radiant heat

Tags: plumbing

Based on my research with 4-5 yurt companies, a yurt's floor needs to be laid before the yurt is set up. If I put down radiant floor mats, then the flooring, how do I put in the plumbing without damaging the mats?

Comment: Could one put down a sub-floor, set up the yurt on the sub-floor, put in the plumbing, insulate the floor, put down the heating mats, put a finished floor over that?

Comment: What type of radiant floor mats do you intend to use? What will be the heat source?

Comment: I assume you have some kind of floor plan...wouldn't you run the necessary plumbing under the floor with connection points poking up through, then lay the floor, then set the yurt up on top of it and continue your plumbing from the connection points?

Comment: The yurt walls are set up directly on top of the flooring so the floor must be completed. Not sure what brand of mats I'd use. Yes, Chris M., I do have a floor plan - your suggestion makes sense. Thank you